# Desalination in Southern California, U.S.A

Tags: united-states, california, infrastructure, water

California is going through a drought. However, there is a lot of water, salt water, to the west.  My understanding is that [Santa Catalina Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Catalina_Island_(California)), west of Southern California, has a desalination plant to generate drinkable water from the ocean. What is the status of creating a desalination plant for Southern California?

There is some prime real estate at San Onofre while [the power plant is being decommissioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Onofre_Nuclear_Generating_Station).

Comment: So, why the downvote?  Isn't the status of a desalination plant based on politics?

Comment: desalination is (currently) extremely energy intensive. most of socal's water goes to irrigation, not drinking. that's not a cost-effective way of growing crops.

Comment: @dandavis that's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Your question is unclear as to whether a So Cal desalination plant is planned / exists and is held up by some political process, or if you're just wondering if one might happen. The former is an on-topic question, the latter probably isn't.

Comment: https://watershed.ucdavis.edu/shed/lund/students/Gellerman2013.pdf

Comment: I don't know why the downvote was given, but reasons may have included "does not show any research effort; it is unclear ..." Basic research would have revealed that CA has [12 Existing Seawater Desalination Facilities](https://www.waterboards.ca.gov/water_issues/programs/ocean/desalination/docs/170105_desal_map_existing.pdf) including one at Carlsbad, which is south of San Onofre. Adding such *basic research* and *asking about possible plans for San Onofre* to the question may help to get it re-opened.

Comment: @Rick Smith The question wording could be improved for sure, but it's not fair to say that the question "doesn't show research effort" merely because there already are desal plants. To be more fair, the question should be interpreted as "Why is desal market share so tiny, given all the dire warnings about California running out of water?" Since these dire warnings are inherently political, the question is political in nature -- even if the answer is mostly about economics, as the other commenters have noted.

Comment: @phoog Good observation: answers go in the comments because answers posted as answers are not allowed here (at least until the question is reopened).

Comment: To expand on dandavis's answer: The real question here is why is there a perception that there should be more desalination plants than there already are. Outsiders hear the lawn irrigation restrictions and don't understand how water budgets actually work. The state doesn't actually cut off irrigation water (assuming you pay your bills). There's a penalty structure, which acts as a 300% tax on lawn water. But the wholesale prices are under $2K/AF and there are still plenty of supply options (besides desal) at those prices. For instance, the new 4MAF storage just announced.

Comment: @personal_cloud the question was not closed when I posted that comment.